# When generating a project with Angular CLI version 15.0.4. I get this error

Tags: angular, github

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNOfE.png)

This is been shown each time when I try to run the command > **ng build --prod --base-href "https://IjaasMohamed.github.io/movies-app/" **

Although everything from creation of a repository to **commiting **changes to them went well, when i try to deploy using the GitHub I have been forced with the this error. I have been trying to deploy the project via GitHub.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add formatted code. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035)

Answer (score 1):

`--prod` was deprecated in favor of `--configuration=production` or short `--c=production`.

Comment: Yes! Noted and solved as by the instructions